# Tiles vertically displaced

Tags: openlayers-3

I'am trying to use ol3. I have started with basic usage. This is the used code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">
  <head>
    <title>SGS</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ol.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/ol.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        renderer:'canvas',
        layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.XYZ({url: 'tiles/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png'}),
          extent:ol.proj.transformExtent([12,-48.5,19,-51], 'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857')
        })],
        view: new ol.View({center: [1605991, -6461852], zoom: 10, maxZoom: 13})
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0px">
    <div id="map" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Tiles are stored locally. Result yields horizontal stripes:
[image]
Tested in Chrome 41 and IE 10 with the same result.

Comment: tiles were downloaded using jTileDownloader 0.6.1 from http://ttiles03.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/vy/sat/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the tile url:

```
url: 'tiles/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png'
```

You are using `{-y}` which is for [TMS](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Maps#TileMapServicesTMS) services. In your case for MapQuest tiles you should use `{y}`.

```
url: 'tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
```

Comment: I tryed 'tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png' url scheme, but tiles belong somewhere else. IMHO the problem is that openlayers align tiles to the grid using diffenet tile corner. EDIT: leaflet does not suffer from this problem

Comment: I missed that you are also changing the extent of `ol.layer.Tile`. Try without setting the extent.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a TMS, not an XYZ. The important difference is that they have different origins for their tile numbering schemes: top-left and bottom-left. I just encountered this issue trying to add a TMS, using a `ol.layer.Tile` with a `ol.source.XYZ` source as you were trying to do. The solution is to use the [`tileUrlFunction`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/apidoc/ol.html#TileUrlFunctionType) option for the `ol.source.XYZ, and adapt the y tile coordinate for the TMS origin (bottom-left x,y is 0,0):

```
tileUrlFunction: function(tileCoord, pixelRatio, projection) {
  var x, y, z;
  z = tileCoord[0];
  x = tileCoord[1];
  y = tileCoord[2] + (1 << z);
  // substitute these into the url, which this function must return
```